# Pytest не видит статические файлы Fastapi

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi

Всем привет!

Пытаюсь протестировать роут fastapi используя pytest, но ругается что не видит директорию

```
test_page.py:None (test_page.py)
test_page.py:3: in <module>
    from server import fastapi_app
../server.py:8: in <module>
    fastapi_app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
../lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/staticfiles.py:55: in __init__
    raise RuntimeError(f"Directory '{directory}' does not exist")
E   RuntimeError: Directory 'static' does not exist
```

Если просто запустить сервер, то все корректно отображается и шаблоны с css подтягиваются без ошибок

Подскажите как это победить?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Исправил